# How to define email address with Jmeter user defined variables?

Tags: jmeter

**Problem:** In email address @ replaced by %40.

**http header manager:**

[image]

**user defined variables:**

[image]

**http request:**

[image]

**and result tree:**

[image]

I have researched about this, and they say that, if http method is POST, then it should encoded automatically. But It does not encoded automatically. Any advice, how can I resolve this?

**Note:** Jmeter version : 3.1 and I am trying to test a rest service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. @PoorvajaDeshmukh's answer suggest me. Like following (correct defination of body data);

[image]

I also tried @DmitriT's suggestion, but I did not work. Thanks for advices...

Answer (score 1):

Please try sending data in Body data instead of sending it in parameters.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change "Implementation" of your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to `Java`

[image: JMeter HTTP Client Implementation]

If you need to change it for more than one sampler - it makes sense to define the setting using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults).